# Add multiple columns to PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

For every dataframe row I need to make a REST call and use response in order to create multiple columns in the dataframe.
I see the following nasty solution:

- add temporary column `response` which will contain the response
- build needed columns from `response`
- finally remove `response`

What is the proper way to solve my problem?

Comment: to add the column `df = df.withColumn('response', response)`, to remove the column `df = df.drop('response')`. To build needed columns based on it, we'll need more information for your data.

Comment: i would say, making REST call for each row of the spark dataframe is not an ideal approach.

Comment: @hprakash, why?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the task with the help of `rdd.mapPartitions`. This seems to be the best solution.